# Ruby PDF Reader Stack Smashing Detection

Tags: ruby, pdf

I am using the default ruby `PDF::Reader` and I am using `ImageMagick` to extract images out of the `pdf`. I am getting an error while trying to read the `pdf` saying that a stack smashing attack was detected. How can fix the `pdf` so that it does not trip that error while I am reading it.

Comment: A stack smashing attack is designed to exploit buffer overflow vulnerabilities. If you've displayed that PDF on your system using another reader that wasn't able to detect and stop this, you may want to check if your system has been compromised.

Answer (score 0):

pdf-reader is a pure ruby library, so it's unlikely to be the root cause.

How are you using imagemagick? If you're using a compiled rubygem, them it possibly has a bug. There are a few options for using imagemagick from ruby, so you could try one of the alternatives.

Can you provide the simplest script possible that triggers the issue and a copy of the exact error message?